# Shopify Public APP, remove app code before Uninstall

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm using this https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify package to develop Shopify public APP.

I tried to remove the code from the theme on uninstalling the app by overriding the AppUninstalledJob.
But, the function can't remove the code from the theme.

I have set the webhook for app uninstall, I getting the webhook response from shopify but API's are not getting call.

The similar issue I found here:

### https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/issues/188

I want to make an API call on app uninstall, can anyone help me with this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to make any API calls when your app is uninstalled. Once this happens, you lose any rights to do so as your API access token received on installation is also deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

Another point to be made here, if you are messing with a theme using your App, injected code into themes, you are doing it wrong. You should be ensuring that whatever you do, if a customer uninstalls your App, their theme is not destroyed by having a bunch of bad code in it. So that means you probably use script tags, proxy calls and as a last resort, create copies of theme files, and edit only those, so the merchant can replace your theme files with the originals.

In 2020 Shopify is allowing Apps to provide Theme Sections, so Apps that mess up themes should just disappear too.